Unable to access symlinks from htdocs
I am a beginner with the LAMP stack and I am using xampp/8.2.12 for a php/8.2.12  project. The project is stored in my home folder. To serve the project in localhost I have created the symlink from project folder to htdocs.
I have also changed httpd-xampp.conf to Require all granted. However I am still getting the error Error 403: Access Forbidden.
I have tried all the solutions in this forum but am still unable to get it working.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; and your php version only matches unsupported or EOL releases of Ubuntu.

No no, I was just frustrated that he always points out that I am using an end of life version of Ubuntu. Actually I want to update to the latest LTS but there are problems. I have seen his profile and I am really happy that someone of his calliber is pointing out my errors.

Just an FYI:  But understanding what software stack you're using (and age of stack is rather important) and I consider the starting point for exploring issues.  Versions can be found via https://packages.ubuntu.com/ or a CLI enquiry which will show Ubuntu repository versions (from term I can also see Debian releases)  so details of release can be obtained where versions (not release) are given too. You didn't provide release details; so I explored versions & it came back...

ok noted. will take care from next time.
